# Uncertainty of an observable when on energy eigenstate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

Suppose we are on an energy eigenstate
$$ \varphi_n $$
We can calculate the expected value
$$ <[\hat H , \hat A ] >_{φ_n} $$ and show that it will be equal to zero.
Now, according to [Robertson uncertainty relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations) , using the above result  we can show that when the system is on an energy eigenstate we can measure the observable which corresponds to $$ \hat A $$ as accurately as we want.

If we set for example $$ \hat A = \hat x $$ then  $$ΔxΔH>= 0  (?!)$$
What's the problem with my reasoning ?

Comment: "we can show that when the system is on an energy eigenstate we can measure the observable which corresponds to $A$
as accurately as we want." This is obviously false. Energy eigenstates are not magical states that make them eigenstates of all other operators $A$ too.

Comment: This has nothing to do with energy eigenstates. If you have a hermitian operator B and an eigenstate of that operator $|\Psi\rangle$, then $\sigma_B^2 = \langle B^2\rangle - \langle B \rangle^2 = 0$. Hence any product with $\sigma_B$ will be zero. But you say choose $A=x$ and then you look at the product $\sigma_x\sigma_p$ instead of $\sigma_x\sigma_H$. The point is that when you have two operators that do not commute, you cannot have simultaneous eigenstates. So when you are in a position eigenstate, $\sigma_p$ is arbitrarily large.

Comment: I edited my initial post ( i meant to to say ΔH, not Δp)

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, i know that energy eigenstates are not magical states that make them eigenstates of any other operator. My problem is that the robertson uncertainty relation has the expected value of the commutator, which for the given states and the operators mentioned is equal to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... using the above result we can show that when the system is on an energy eigenstate we can measure the observable which corresponds to ̂ as accurately as we want.

Not quite. Recall $[\hat H,\hat x]\neq 0$ even though the expectation thereof vanishes, of course. But nothing in the Robertson inequality, or its derivation, suggests $\Delta x =0$. Your only find, on energy eigenstates,  $\Delta x \Delta H\geq 0$, a tautology.

Consider the SHO, in natural units,
$$
\hat H=\tfrac{1}{2}(\hat p ^2 + \hat x ^2)
$$
and expectation values in its ground state, $E_0=1/2$, $\psi_0=e^{-x^2/2}/\pi^{1/4}$,
$$
\langle \hat x\rangle_0= \langle \hat p\rangle_0=0,\\
\langle \hat x^2\rangle_0= \langle \hat p^2\rangle_0=1/2,\\
\langle \hat  H\rangle_0= 2\langle \hat H^2\rangle_0=1/2,\\
$$
yielding, in the ground state,
$$
\Delta x= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}= \Delta p,\\
\Delta H=0,
$$
all mutually consistent.